# UWP run in Release Mode gives "'ApplicationData' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp

When I run a UWP app in Debug mode, `ApplicationData` exists.

When I run in Release mode, it seems `ApplicationData` has gone out of scope. Rather, accessing it times out.

I've added two lines to a stock UWP Blank page app solution:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string strPath = 
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path; // <<< Added
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strPath);    // <<< Added
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
//...
```

Running in debug mode, `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` exists, and `strPath` is something like...

```
C:\Users\AUser\AppData\Local\Packages\[some guid-like number]_7442be4pe7dnc\LocalState
```

Running in Release mode, if I check up on things in the Immediate Window, I get this...

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,nq
The name 'ApplicationData' does not exist in the current context
```

And hovering over the code itself gives me a strange timeout:

[image]

If `ApplicationData` isn't in scope in a release app, how do I get to the folder? If it is supposed to be in scope, why wouldn't it be here?

---

**EDIT:** Same thing happens when I try to access `ApplicationData` in a click event for a button, so it's not a timing/initialization thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run in Release mode, it seems ApplicationData has gone out of scope. Rather, accessing it times out.

When running your UWP application in release mode. VS build your codes using [.Net Native Tool Chain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/09/the-net-native-tool-chain/) and also optimize the codes by default. And it is not a suitable environment for debugging. But it won't change the output of your codes. You just can't see it in debugger.

You can disable building with .Net Native Tool Chain and codes optimization by following steps:

right click your project file->Properties->`Build` tag on left-> uncheck `Compile with .Net Native tool chain` and uncheck `Optimize code` like below：
[image]

And now you can debug your codes in release mode correctly.

Comment: Yep! Seems like there are some threading issues that only pop up in release (some file reads during UI creation that were happy in Debug), and debugging wasn't much fun.Thanks! (Nice cat, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue in a Windows Application Packaging Project. It was caused by a missing **Default.rd.xml** file in the UWP component. Restoring the file also restored access to ApplicationData.

[Default.rd.xml file in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNHzk.png)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31286000)

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN I was actually adding a path to resolve the root cause of this issue.