# UWP ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is null in release

Tags: uwp

I have this code in startup for a UWP app to access local data

`StorageFolder appDataFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`

This works fine in debug but `appDataFolder` is null in release mode.

Why is this so? How do I access local data in release mode?

Comment: I can’t reproduce your issue, I can access local data in release mode. I suggest you could try to create a new Blank app to check whether this issue still occurs.

Comment: @Arya Ding - MSFT We have an app in the Microsoft Store for about 5 years using this line of code. It was just in testing the latest version before publishing that we struck this issue, so I know it works. But where do I start looking to find out what's wrong?

Comment: I did create a new blank UWP and it can find `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. What can make `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` null?

Comment: Does this issue occur on every PC? My suggestion is that you could test your app on other PCs to check this issue.

Comment: Yes it occurs on our other dev's PC also. Happy to accept we have something in the app causing this, but where to look?

Comment: You could try to check this location(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\...)manually. Besides, what is the detailed error message?

Comment: The folder is there. We get a `NullReferenceException` when we try to reference `appDataFolder.Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [UWP run in Release Mode gives “'ApplicationData' does not exist in the current context”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586545/5528313)
To run in release mode, in properties/debug uncheck Net Native tool chain and uncheck Optimize code[image]

Comment: Thanks you for this! I was also having trouble with Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync() in release mode as well.